# Can a unit vector be treated as a vector field?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, vector-fields, scalar-fields, curl

Say you have the **k**th component of a vector field:

$$\phi \hat{k}$$

Can we treat this as a scalar field $\phi$ multiplied by the vector field $\hat{k}$?

EDIT:

So, if you wanted to find the curl of $\phi \hat{k}$, could you use the following formula with $f$ = $\phi$ and $u$ = $\hat{k}$?

[image]

**u** is typically supposed to be a vector field, and *f* a scalar field.

Comment: Yes ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I've fixed the formatting now

Comment: Do you know what a "vector field" means?

Comment: @banana Yes you're basically assigning a vector to each point in space, why?

Comment: Then are you assigning each "point" the constant vector $\hat k$?

Comment: What space are you talking about? $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: Yes in 3-space but the i and j components of the vector field are 0. It's an odd question but I wanted to know if you can treat a unit vector as a vector field like I've described - I think you can but I thought I might be missing something.

Comment: You don't call a constant vector a "vector field" just like you don't call a number, say $\pi$, a function. You can define a "constant vector field" though, just like you define a "constant function". For instance, define $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ $f(x)=\pi$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your vector field $F:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$ is given by
$$
F(x,y,z)=f_1(x,y,z)i+f_2(x,y,z)j+f_3(x,y,z)k
$$
where $f_j$ are scalar functions. Then yes, $G:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$ with
$$
G(x,y,z)=f_3(x,y,z)k
$$
gives you another vector field. You could call the right-hand side "a scalar field multiplied by a constant vector". (You don't call $k$ a vector field here; it is nothing but a constant vector.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That makes sense. Could you see my edit and see if that makes sense too?